# Load another html page and scroll to inner page div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have main index page which loads all pages in its container using jquery load method.
Now similarly loading another page called aboutus.html and animate to its perticular div how it will be possible.

I am getting uncaught type error offset top not defined.

Code is written in app.js and linked to index.js

App.js code:
Inside document.ready

````
Var el= $("#secid"); // on console it returns object object

$("body, html").animate({
 scrollTop: el.offset().top //here top returns error
},2000);```

Thus navigation on inner page not works so what will be the solution on it
````

Comment: please include the css and the html.

Comment: Style.css also linked

Comment: You should provide us with your css and html here! It is hard to help if we don't know the full scope. Scrolling has more to do with css than it has to do with js.